# Unable to fetch data from textfield using $_POST

Tags: php, forms, http-post, fetch

I have been not able to fetch data from the textfield 'current_reading'. What can be the issue? every other text and `$_POST` method are working fine

index page

```
<body>

<?php
include "connect.php";
?>
<form method="post" action="billing.php">

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="data">
        <div class="label">
        Society
        </div>
        <div class="textfield">
        <input type="text" name="society"  />
        </div>

        <div class="label">
        Customer id
        </div>
        <div class="textfield">
        <input type="text" name="customer_id"  />
        </div>

        <div class="label">
        Customer name
        </div>
        <div class="textfield">
        <input type="text" name="customer_name"  />
        </div>

        <div class="label">
        Wing
        </div>
        <div class="textfield">
        <input type="text" name="wing"  />
        </div>

        <div class="label">
        Flat no
        </div>
        <div class="textfield">
        <input type="text" name="flat_no"  />
        </div>

          <div class="label">
        Previous date
        </div>
        <div class="textfield">
        <input type="text" name="previous_date"  />
        </div>

        <div class="label">
        Previous reading
        </div>
        <div class="textfield">
        <input type="text" name="previous_reading"  />
        </div>


        <div class="label">
        Current date
        </div>
        <div class="textfield">
        <input type="text" name="current_date"  />
        </div>

         <div class="label">
        Current reading
        </div>
        <div class="textfield">
        ***<input type="text" name="current_reading"  />***
        </div>

    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"  />
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Billing

```
<body>
<?php
include "connect.php";
?>

<?php

    $society=$_POST['society'];
    $id=$_POST['customer_id'];
    $name=$_POST['customer_name'];

    $wing=$_POST['wing'];
    $flat_no=$_POST['flat_no'];

    $previous_reading=$_POST['previous_reading'];
    $previous_date=$_POST['previous_date'];

    $current_date=$_POST['current_date'];
    *****$current_reading=$_POST['current_reading'];*****

    if($current_reading=" ")
    {
        echo "current date:".$current_date."<br><br>";
    }

    else
    {
        echo "current reading:".$current_reading."<br><br>";
        echo "previous reading:".$previous_reading."<br><br>";

        $units=($current_reading-$previous_reading);
        echo "units".$units."<br><Br>";

        $rate= mysql_query("select per_unit_rate from charges where society=".$society);

        $amount = $units * $rate;

        $service_charge=mysql_query("select service_charge from charges where society=".$society);

        $net_bill=$amount+$service_charge;

        echo "The amount of net bill is:".$net_bill;

        mysql_query("insert into report values ('$id', '$current_date', '$net_bill','$units')");
    }
?>

<?php
include "connect.php";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I have been not able to fetch data from the textfield 'current reading'(bold and red). What can be the issue? every other text and `$_POST` method are working fine

Comment: your `if($current_reading=" ")` should have at least 2 equal signs `==` `if($current_reading==" ")` and also please see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/2293679

Comment: `XSS` attack will be happy with the above.

Answer (score 2):

change your line code in Billing.php

```
if($current_reading=" ")
{
    echo "current date:".$current_date."<br><br>";
}
```

become

```
if(empty($current_reading))
{
    echo "current date:".$current_date."<br><br>";
}
```

hopefully it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(isset($_POST['current_reading'])){

   $current_reading = $_POST['current_reading'];

}else{

echo 'Current reading is not set';

}
```